# Problem updating weblogic 12.1.1 to 12.1.3

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I have the following problem every time I try to update my domain in weblogic 12.1.1 to 12.1.3, I am using the reconfiguration wizard of version 12.1.3 and it always shows me the following error, I am not an expert with weblogic management, if anyone knows of any strategy or other way to migrate my current domain I would appreciate it

Error:

2023-07-23 12:12:33,868 SEVERE [92] com.oracle.cie.domain.WLSCoreReconfigurator - Reconfiguration failed
com.oracle.cie.domain.ValidateException: CFGFWK-60953: An application or library was not relocated to the new MW home.
CFGFWK-60953: An error in the reconfiguration templates resulted in the following deployments being left in the original MW home:
state-management-provider-memory-rar-12.1.3

CFGFWK-60953: Correct the reconfiguration templates
at com.oracle.cie.domain.WLSCoreReconfigurator.validateDeployments(WLSCoreReconfigurator.java:757)
at com.oracle.cie.domain.WLSCoreReconfigurator.run(WLSCoreReconfigurator.java:322)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2023-07-23 12:12:33,869 SEVERE [92] com.oracle.cie.domain.WLSCoreReconfigurator - Reconfiguration Failed!

Exception:

CFGFWK-60953: An application or library was not relocated to the new MW home.
CFGFWK-60953: An error in the reconfiguration templates resulted in the following deployments being left in the original MW home:
state-management-provider-memory-rar-12.1.3

CFGFWK-60953: Correct the reconfiguration templates
com.oracle.cie.domain.ValidateException: CFGFWK-60953: An application or library was not relocated to the new MW home.
CFGFWK-60953: An error in the reconfiguration templates resulted in the following deployments being left in the original MW home:
state-management-provider-memory-rar-12.1.3

CFGFWK-60953: Correct the reconfiguration templates
at com.oracle.cie.domain.WLSCoreReconfigurator.validateDeployments(WLSCoreReconfigurator.java:757)
at com.oracle.cie.domain.WLSCoreReconfigurator.run(WLSCoreReconfigurator.java:322)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

The latest PSU for WLS 12.1.3 was released on January 2020, since then that version is receiving more updates. Why are you trying to update your domain to a version that ended its ECP? Why don't you use a version covered by ECP? like 12.2.1.4.

Anyway to update your domain, you need to install the new WLS in a different folder, making a new ORACLE_HOME.

Example:

If the old WLS 12.1.1 is installed at /refresh/home/oracle/wls1211, then install the new one in /refresh/home/oracle/wls12214.

Then run the re-configuration wizard from the new installation (ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/reconfig.sh), passing as parameter the location of your old domain. As a result, your old domain will remain in the same original location, but it will be pointing to the new binaries. This process will be as complicated as the components you have in your domain and if they support the new binaries. It is possible that some components require additional steps to complete an upgrade.

Ref:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/upgrade.html

Comment: Yes, I initially tried the version 12.1.3 but then I tried it with 12.2.1.4 but basically it's the same error and I followed the guide that you describe in your answer, but I couldn't get past that.